# I'm trying to use Dynamic Buttons by a GitHub source but the do not work

Tags: ios, xcode

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicButton: DynamicButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dynamicButton = DynamicButton(style: DynamicButtonStyle.hamburger)
    dynamicButton.setStyle(DynamicButtonStyle.close, animated: true)

   }
```

I'm getting the hamburger button with a bounce effect but I cannot see any transition.

This is the source : https://github.com/YannickL/DynamicButton

Comment: This is the third almost identical question I've seen in the past few days. Perhaps you should ask the creator of that button to include instructions on how to use it. As far as I can see, it is a standard UIButton subclass, which means you can use it just like any other UIButton.

Comment: Checked not working.

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: The button doesn't show transition.

Comment: OK - you'll need to be a little more detailed. The code you have posted simply creates a DynamicButton object, but does not add it to a view, or assign any functionality to it. Does the button "work" in the Example provided at that GitHub repo?

Comment: yes it does, but it the project attached in the GitHub repo is just to depict the animation shown in collection view. I've tried almost everything but the animation and segue doesn't take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing styles on tap...

Create a segue to your destination view controller. Give it an identifier, such as "destSegue". Add `Touch Down`, `Touch Up Inside` and `Touch Up Outside` IBActions, as follows:

```
@IBAction func didTouchDown(_ sender: Any) {

    if let b = sender as? DynamicButton {

        b.setStyle(.plus, animated: true)

    }

}

@IBAction func didTouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    if let b = sender as? DynamicButton {

        b.setStyle(.hamburger, animated: true)

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "destSegue", sender: self)

    }

}

@IBAction func didTouchUpOutside(_ sender: Any) {

    if let b = sender as? DynamicButton {

        b.setStyle(.hamburger, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Note that if you tap quickly on the button, you will probably not see the full animation cycle. To allow that, you'll need to edit the source of the DynamicButton and add completion blocks or delegate callbacks.

Comment: I am using the "Dynamic Button" in my main ViewController to take me to another ViewController but when I tap the button it takes my to another ViewController without the animation being able to see. The segue works fine but no transition.

Comment: What animation are you expecting? When I set it up, I tap the button... it gets a little bit larger... I lift my finger... as it goes back to its normal size the new view segues in. Are you expecting something else to happen?

Comment: I'm also getting the enlargement effect but I want the hamburger icon to change animation with the cross and new view to segue in.

Comment: OK - that's a little more clear. It does not appear that this "DynamicButton" is designed to do what you want - there is no facility for a completion block or callback. Shouldn't be too tough to implement though.

Comment: are you getting the animation with the hamburger button ? like its shown in the gif  in which it changes to cross and back to hamburger.

Comment: The button from that GitHub can show an animation going from one style to another - such as hamburger to plus. It also animates on touch-down and touch-up. It is *not* designed to animate from one style on touch-down to another style and then back on touch-up. See my edited answer for one option...

Comment: Do I have to use a custom segue ?

Comment: This is ONE WAY to accomplish what you want. Try it yourself with a 'regular' segue and with performSegue(). If you like the way it looks with a segue connected to the button, great. If not, then you probably need to use performSegue(). Of course, you can always contact the creator of this custom button and ask him/her to add the functionality for you.

Comment: I'm getting a SIGABRT error while performing Touch Down, Touch Up Inside and Touch Up Outside IBActions, it shows the cross from the Hamburger but then it shows the error.

Comment: You're getting a SIGABRT because you had created and then deleted either an IBOutlet or IBAction. Clean up your code / storyboard, or restart from scratch, and you won't see that error.